How to Prove Segment Equality in a Parallelogram Derived from an Equilateral Triangle?
The problem is written like this:
The leg of an equilateral triangle is 5m long. From the point that lies on the base of this triangle, two lines are drawn parallel to its legs. Find the perimeter of the resulting parallelogram.
I tried to solve this like this:
The opposite sides of the resulting parallelogram are equal in length.
I was wondering if we can somehow prove that ED=AE. If we can prove it, then we can make an equation to find the perimeter. But I am not being able to prove it. Could you help please?
By the way, it is my first time asking a question on this platform, so if I did something wrong, I would be more than happy to read suggestions to improve my question-asking.


Hint: you have not used the fact that the triangle is equilateral.

What are the angles in $\triangle AED$?

@EthanBolker, here is my renewed thoughts based on the hint you gave: as the triangle is equilateral, AB=BC=5m. So, AE+EB=BF+FC. From this equation we can see that EB=FC and AE=BF, but still I am not sure whether I correctly proved their equality in this way.

@Andrei, none of the angles were given.

All angles in $\triangle AED$ are $60^\circ$. The original triangle is equilateral, so $\angle EAD=\angle BAC=60^\circ$. The others you can get from the fact that $AB$ intersects two parallel lines, and so does $AC$. Then $DE=AE$, so $DE+EB=AE+EB=AB=5$

@Andrei, thanks much for the explanation. I completely ignored the fact that equilateral triangles have 60º angles. Thanks Ethan Bolker, too What will I do with this question page, I mean should I mark this question as done?

If you now know the answer you should either answer your own question and accept your answer, or delete the question.

First, please note that $ADE$ and $CDF$ are both equilateral triangles, as, by construction, they are similar to $ABC$. The desired perimeter is $P = \text{Perimeter}(EBFD) = EB + BF + FD + DE$. But, because $EBFD$ is a parallelogram, $EB = FD$ and $BF = DE$, and thus $P = 2(FD + DE)$. Now, because $CDF$ is equilateral, $FD = DC$. Similarly, because $ADE$ is equilateral, $DE = AD$. So now we have : $P = 2(DC + AD) = 2 AC = 2 \times 5 = 10 \text{ m}$.

The triangles are similar, not congruent. What does your answer add in addition to the comments to the question?

Yes I meant "similar", not congruent indeed. My answer gives the full reasoning to get to the final result.
